# Summarize output

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I have been stuck for a while on this. I  ran a simulation in Fortran90.

```
  program epidemic
implicit none

!!!variable declaration 
integer, parameter::n=625
 real, dimension(1:n)::x,y
 real :: alpha, beta, epsilon, dist, prob, u
   integer, dimension(1:n) :: infections 
 integer:: T, I1, I2, I3, i, j, K2, infperiod, k, tmax


!!!!!!!!!! paramater value 
tmax=11
alpha=0.4
gamma=9

!!Generate population!!
I3=1
Do I1=1, 25, 1
  Do I2=1,25,1
       x(I3)=REAL(I1)
       y(I3)=REAL(I2)
       Infections(I3)=0
       I3=I3+1

    ENDDO
ENDDO



!!!INITIAL INFECTION!!!

call random_number(u)
k2=1+aint(u)*n
infections(k2)=1








!!!! initial infection !!!!!!
     call random_number(u)
          IF (prob >= u) THEN 

        END IF
     END IF



    ENDDO
    enddo



 !!! output data  

 !!! writing and saving 

 Do i= 1, n 

  write(*,*) i, x(i), y(i)
 ENDDO



end program epidemic
```

The result of my simulation is a data frame that looks like this

```
       1   1.00000000       1.00000000               1
       2   1.00000000       2.00000000               4
       3   1.00000000       3.00000000               3
       4   1.00000000       4.00000000               4
       5   1.00000000       5.00000000               4
       6   1.00000000       6.00000000               4
       7   1.00000000       7.00000000               4
       8   1.00000000       8.00000000               2
       9   1.00000000       9.00000000               4
      10   1.00000000       10.0000000               4
      11   1.00000000       11.0000000               5
      12   1.00000000       12.0000000               5
      13   1.00000000       13.0000000               4
      14   1.00000000       14.0000000               5
      15   1.00000000       15.0000000               6
```

The first column represents the individuals  such that i=1, 625, The second and third column represents the matrix indices [i,j]. The forth column represents the  (time) (1:15 days) the person get the infections. I would like to be able to table the output into just two columns.

Just to illustrate, I would like to create a new variable that show the  many people got infected in this day.

So, the output of the 625 rows becomes something like this

```
                            AT Day=1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 
     Total of infected individual =3 5 6 7 11 8 0 1 ...........
```

Thank you very very much

Comment: Don't vandalize questions by deleting important code on which answers are based on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that it's clear what you have, try this:

Add a new declaration

```
integer, dimension(15) :: infection_day
```

and, after your existing loop `do T ...`, insert something like

```
do i = 1, 15
    infection_day(i) = count(infections==i)
end do
```

to summarise your data.

I don't have Fortran on this machine so haven't tested this code fragment, but it should put you on the right track.

Comment: Thank you very much @High Performance Mark. Your method did what I have been struggling with. Again, I deeply thank you for answering me.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started...

```
...
INTEGER, DIMENSION(31) :: Sums
!day is the 4th column from 1:625...
...
Sums(:) = 0
...
DO Entry = 1, 625
  Sums(Thedayindex) = Sums(Thedayindex) + Day(Entry)
ENDDO
...
```

Comment: Probably some typo, did you mean `Sums(Entry)`?

Comment: Correct... If the OP wants the # of occursnces by day of the month, then they need to sum each occurance's day of the month that the event occurs, into 31day bins... So I again had a typo ;(  The easiest to understand is a bunch of if, else if to add into the day SUMS, but it is quicker and easier to get the logic right by summing directly into the proper bin (IMO).

Comment: In that case there is at least one more typo. `Sum` vs `Sums`

Comment: Backing in 1991 I wrote a program that compiled and ran the first time. I was pretty proud of that until the grey-beard said, "these days you are waiting time if you are not letting the computer catch those mistakes"... You would swear that I learned English after Martian, but I just have a lot of typos... ;(

Comment: Sorry I thought I was clear :((( I am very nw to fortran and I just added the code here. Thank yo very much.

Comment: So sxq2221 does that mean it all worked and you are happy now?